# WP7 Button content is not being displayed

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, hyperlink, textblock

I am creating a hyperlink button like this:

```
HyperlinkButton hlbMail = new HyperlinkButton();
        hlbMail.Height = 89;
        hlbMail.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        hlbMail.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
        hlbMail.Margin = new Thickness(60, -70, 0, 0);
        hlbMail.Width = 290;      
        hlbMail.FontSize = 22;

        TextBlock btnContent = new TextBlock();

        btnContent.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        btnContent.Text = message;
        btnContent.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        hlbMail.Content = btnContent;

        hlbMail.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        mailStackPanel.Children.Add(hlbMail);

        mailscrollViewer.Content = mailStackPanel;
        PIMail.Content = mailscrollViewer;
```

But i have a problem in which the content of the button is not being displayed. As can be seen, the content is supposed to be the text of the TextBlock (the message var is a string which is not empty). What can be the reason that the content is not being shown?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this:
hlbMail.Content= btnContent.Text;
I think you forgot to add the .Text.

You cannot have a hyperlinkbutton having textblock as its content. But you can have the text of a textblock as the content of the hyperlink

As you also mentioned you need the text of textblock than you need to specify that you need the text by adding the btnContent.Text;

Comment: I'm not in front of my own computer right now but if i do it then will the wrapping of the text remains? Since my main reason of doing what i did what in order to use the text wrapping

Comment: Yes it will not effect textwrapping or any other property. YOu just need to change this line: hlbMail.Content = btnContent;
To this hlbMail.Content = btnContent.Text;

Comment: As you want to show the text of Textblock in your Hyperlink. You cannot do that by specifying that you want to. And by using the .Text, you are telling to use the text. It will not effect other properties.

Comment: the text is being displayed but its not wrapping. The content slide over the margins of the button's borders

Comment: Very well than look at this... its if you can modify your xml... than by this method you can add text wrap to you hyperlinkbut. http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1761-text-wrap-hyperlink-button-control-silverlight.aspx
Or you can add the textButton (which you are dinamically adding) using xml and than change the text of that button. As a result the text of the hyperlink button will also change... That is if you are using the method given in the above link

Comment: since I'm adding it dynamically then the xml option won't do and i didn't really understand your second option.. what is the difference between what you suggested and what is already happening in the method?

Comment: In the second option do as the tut tells you to do i.e make the hyperlinkbutton and then inside it add the button(in xaml). After that edit the text of the textblock from c# file.

Comment: Talla i just turned everything into a text block and used the double tap event in order to navigate